# CSS display list in columns

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a list which is made by Vue.js

Here is my code:

```html
<ul>
    <li
        v-for="category in item.children"
        :key="category.id"
        class="menu-item"
    >
        <nuxt-link
            :to="
                localePath(
                    `/category/${category.slug}/${category.id}`
                )
            "
        >
            <h5>{{ category.lang[0].name }}</h5>
        </nuxt-link>
        <ul class="mega-menu__list">
            <li
                v-for="subItem in category.children"
                :key="subItem.id"
            >
                <nuxt-link
                    :to="
                        localePath(
                            `/category/${subItem.slug}/${subItem.id}`
                        )
                    "
                >
                    {{ subItem.lang[0].name }}
                </nuxt-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

But I want it to display like this which child is in the same column:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer depends on your current styles. Can you update the question to include the CSS?

Comment: Oh my god... A list inside a list... where the first list is not a list but a `div` and each `li` is a `section`...

Comment: @matiaslauriti what is your recommendation to change this?

Comment: Think that everything is a box, if it is a "list of menus" then, each different menu is a box, so each menu should be in a `div` or `section` (they have to have a parent `div` because they are the whole thing). Then, each menu can be a `ul` from each section. Still, doing so, will not prevent your content from showing as you want, but at least will not cut a menu in half. The parent block has to have a defined height or use `grid` box.

Comment: @matiaslauriti sorry, but i dont really understand what you said, can you show me sample coding?

Comment: Yes, give me some minutes as I code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 450px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

h5 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <h5>shop by concern</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>Pores</li>
            <li>Whitening</li>
            <li>Fine Lines &amp; Wrinkles</li>
            <li>Hydrating</li>
            <li>Dark Spots</li>
            <li>Anti-Aging</li>
            <li>Acne &amp; Blemishes</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>others</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>Tools &amp; Accessories</li>
            <li>Beauty Supplements</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>skincare package</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>treatment</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>T-Zone &vert; Blackhead</li>
            <li>Ampoule</li>
            <li>Acne &vert; Blemishes</li>
            <li>Serum</li>
            <li>Pore Care</li>
            <li>Lip Care</li>
            <li>Eye Care</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>cleanser &amp; exfoliator</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>Scrub &amp; Exfoliator</li>
            <li>Face Wash &amp; Cleansers</li>
            <li>Soap</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>sun care</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>moisturizer</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>Mist Spray</li>
            <li>Cream</li>
            <li>Moisturizer / Lotion</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h5>toner</h5>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

See in my example, that if you have enough `height` (`css`), a menu will try to get there, if not, it will go to the right (because it has space to go there because of `flex-wrap: wrap`. Play with each CSS property in `section` and `div`, and you will understand more.

You can see more about `flex` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). And if you want to try out `grid`, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).